# Stream of documentreference is not updating

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named "cars" and a "user" collection.
Every "user"-document contains of a list of car references.

I have tried multiple ways to get a stream of all "car"-document that the user have in its
"myCars"-list.

My problem is that the stream in my StreamBuilder is not updating when the myCar list changes.

My current code is described below.

I have also tried fetching all "car"-documents by querying the the "car" collection using the "whereIn" operator and an array with the cars doc id's. This also worked, but firestore only allows 10 entries in the "whereIn" operator and that is not working out for me. A user can have more than 10 entries in his list.

I feel that I'm not creating the car stream in the correct way.
Is my datamodel not set up in best practice for this scenario or am I missing a querying feature in firestore?

Car Collection

```
{
    "docId": 123,
    "carName": "volvo",
    "rating": 6.3
}
```

User Collection

```
{
    userId: "userIdField",
    myCars: [
        {
            "carDoc": 123,
            "favourite": true
        },
        {
            "carDoc": 124,
            "favourite": true
        },
        {
            "carDoc": 125,
            "favourite": false
        }
    ]    
}
```

I have this function for fetching the User-Stream

```
Stream<User> fetchUser(String uid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(USER_COLLECTION)
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .asStream()
        .map((event) {
            if (event.data().isNotEmpty) {
                var user = new User();
                user.userId = uid;
                user.carDocs = List.from((event.data()['carDoc'])
                    .map((e) => User(e['carDoc'] as DocumentReference, e['favourite'] as bool)));
                return user;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        );
}
```

I create my widgets like this.

```
child: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: userService.fetchUser(user.uid),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> user) {
            if (!user.hasData) {
                return Text("meh");
            }

            return FutureBuilder(
                future: Future.wait(user.data.myCars.map((e) => e.carDoc.get()).toList()),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> dss) {
                    if (!dss.hasData) {
                        return Text("next meh");
                    }
                    return ListView(
                        children: _build(dss.data.map((e) => createCarWidgtItem(e)).toList()),
                    );
                },
            );
        },
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind, if I omit stream and language perspective and focus on the database structure.

When I look at it, I have a thought that NoSQL database is used in relational/SQL way. Which means that one collection store relation to other collection. In such situation I think PostgreSQL will be better, which is also available on GCP in Cloud SQL.

On the other hand, maybe it would be better to change `myCars` field which is currently an array (at least it seems form description) into sub-collection where every user will have full cars objects.

I know the solution is redundant (means many users can have same cars in their favorites), however this is the idea of NoSQL database. Data is redundant, but you have everything in one place and you do not have to query trough all the collections.

In situation as in presented example you will not have to build sophisticated queries to get a list of user favorite cars (please treat it as pseudo code):

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(USER_COLLECTION)
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('myCars')
        .where("faviorite", isEqualTo: true)
        .get()
```

Or even you can store only favorite cars in users `myCars` collection that you can omit both `where` method and `favorite` boolean field.

Comment: The thing is that the car document is updated several times a day. I don't want to update all users list of car data. I have been thinking of writing my own backend using good old sql. But I would like to have the firebase as my only backend.

Comment: Maybe you could thing of some data structure ex. to every car doc add array of following users. Than when looking for user favorite cars you can query using array-contains particular userid